# PHP Parsing Help, Content rendered in JS not displaying

Tags: php

Currently I am trying to grab the transactions from my Snowtrace (Avalanche) block-chain GUI. Their API does not support what I am currently trying to access. Here's my code, made simply to identify the problem.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://snowtrace.io/token/0xf693248F96Fe03422FEa95aC0aFbBBc4a8FdD172?a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
print $html;
```

This returns the pages content, but excludes the content inside of the `table` structure, that appears to be rendered via Javacript. If I can't gather this information using `file_get_html` how can I grab it?

For those unfamiliar **Simple_html_dom** can be found by [clicking here](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/).

Comment: You can get `https://snowtrace.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=0xf693248f96fe03422fea95ac0afbbbc4a8fdd172&mode=&sid=53bb36c0365e2088d01c5c4877e7ee03&a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000&m=normal&p=1`